# Can't send email with Laravel in Plesk

Tags: laravel, email, plesk

I'm trying to send emails using smtp in plesk but it keeps giving me the error below and I can't fix this even after searching for related solutions:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/public/../../storage/framework/maintenance.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/:/tmp/) in /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/public/index.php on line 19', referer: https://xxxx.com/email/verify
```

I have this in public/index.php

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require __DIR__.'/../../storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}
```

This is my default open_basedir path:

```
{WEBSPACEROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/}
```

And this my configuration in .env file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=xxx.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS='noreply@xxxx.com'
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I'd be really thankful if anyone could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the real path to the storage folder?

If its path is `/var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/storage` you have to change the path in `public/index.php` from `__DIR__.'/../../storage/framework/maintenance.php'` to `__DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php'`

If its path is `/var/www/vhosts/storage` then this path is is not within the allowed paths.